# Automatic login to website with correct credentials fails

Tags: selenium-webdriver, scrapy

I was trying to login to a website with the selenium webdriver and python (scrapy). I have done this a few times already on other sites but this time, when I try to automate the login with the correct credentials, it says it does not recognize my credentials.

I have checked that the credentials I use to login manually and automatically are 100% the same. I think it has something to do with the fact that this website notices that I am using selenium. So I tried to alter the variable $cdc_ in the chromedriver.exe file to xxxx_ with a hex editor but I still got the message that my credentials were'nt recognized.

Hoping someone can help me solve my problem!

```
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from scrapy.selector import Selector

username = 'username'
password = 'password'
class Spider2Spider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'spider2'
    allowed_domains = ['www.bet365.nl']
    start_urls = ['http://www.bet365.nl/']    
    
    def __init__(self):
        chrome_options = Options() 
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
        action = ActionChains(driver)
        driver.get("https://www.bet365.nl")

        driver.maximize_window()
                 
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='hm-   MainHeaderRHSLoggedOutWide_Login ']").click()
    
        WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.XPATH, "//div[@class='lms-StandardLogin_InputsContainer ']/input"))
    )
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='lms-StandardLogin_InputsContainer ']/input").send_keys(username)
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='lms-StandardLogin_InputsContainer lms-StandardLogin_InputsContainer-password ']/input").send_keys(password)
        # driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='lms-LoginButton_Text ']").click()

    def parse(self, response):
        pass
```

Comment: "(can provide code if needed)" - indeed: Your question currently states that you're doing everything right to your knowledge. But obviously you don't. Please read [ask], and edit your question to create a [mcve]

Comment: @OlafKock ok thank you for the feedback, I have added the code